# How do I zoom in on the PC version of Fez?

Tags: fez

I was watching a youtube walkthrough that showed someone [zooming in the Fez camera](https://youtu.be/h4nLDTso7kA?t=14).

[image: controls screen]

This is what I see when I go into controls. I only see "Zoom in" and "Zoom out" for the map, but no mention of zooming in the actual game. Anyone know how I can zoom in inside the game?

Comment: What happens when you press the look button?

Comment: @Timelord64 wtf is the wkl button?

Comment: oh it's IJKL haha

Comment: @Aequitas, that had me stumped, aswell. I thought it was a W, but capital W prints differantly in the other cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't "zooming in" what you are seeing is "First Person View".

You can only do this in New Game+ mode where you are granted glasses that allow this first person view.

Once you unlock it you can push: <kbd>i</kbd>,<kbd>j</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>l</kbd> to use it.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. I guess the interface just comes down to designer flaw.